# Can't access other drives after installing elementary

Tags: mount

I installed elementary OS and I can't seem to access drive D: and E:

Previously, it used to show that it could not mount. 
Right now, it does not show anything. The drives do not open at all.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, if you shutdown windows 10 it does not shut down, but hibernates and that's why you cannot mount the drive where it resists. If you restart it and log on into elementary os then you have access to the windows drives but sometimes there are problems with the audio for example. So the best solution for me is to restart windows,on the choose os screen to shutdown the computer and then start it again into elementary os.

Comment: Th problem is that I uninstalled Windows. I formatted the partition C: while installing. Therefore I do not have windows anymore.

Comment: But can you see the drives D and E using GParted? I mean, are you sure you did not format them too?